# Returning Image from WP REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm trying to use the wp rest api to return a list of posts from a blog, including title, excrpt and featured image. Using the below I can return the title and excerpt but the featured image causes *Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array*.

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

```
$posts = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://wordpressurl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed'));

foreach ( $posts as $post ) 
{
    echo '<a href="'.$post->link.'">
            <img src="'.$post->_embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url.'"/> 
            '.$post->title->rendered, $post->excerpt->rendered.'</a>';
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved this myself using the following:

```
$posts = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://wordpressurl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed'), true);
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    echo '<a href="'.$post[link].'">
        <img src="'.$post[_embedded]['wp:featuredmedia']['0'][source_url].'"/> 
        '.$post[title][rendered], $post[excerpt][rendered].'</a>';
};
```

Adding `true` to the `json_decode` returns an array rather than objects.

I'm sure there's a far cleaner way to do it but for now I'm happy that it works.

Answer (score -1):

Use this type of code

```
$posts = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost/sikkimpwd-apis/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed'));
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    //get attached image id
    $attach_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->id );
    //get image src from attached id
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attach_id,'full')[0];
    echo '<a href="'.$post->link.'"><img src="'.$image_src.'"/> '.$post->title->rendered, $post->excerpt->rendered.'</a>';
};
```

Comment: Explain what you changed and why that would solve the problem.

Comment: This removes the error but doesn't return the image. the outputted html for the featured image is `<img src=""/>`

Comment: Hi,Your main error part is $post->_embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url. So that at first i have collect the attached image id of post from this get_post_thumbnail_id($post->id ), Then collect the url of that image from the attached image id wp_get_attachment_image_src($attach_id,'full')[0]. Then I have used it into img src field.